# Capitalizing non-ASCII words in Python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, capitalization

How to capitalize words containing non-ASCII characters in Python? Is there a way to tune `string`'s `capitalize()` method to do that?

Answer (score 10):

Use Unicode strings:

```
# coding: cp1252
print u"é".capitalize()
# Prints É
```

If all you have is an 8-bit string, decode it into Unicode first:

```
# coding: cp1252
print "é".decode('cp1252').capitalize()
# Prints É
```

If you then need it as an 8-bit string again, encode it:

```
# coding: cp1252
print "é".decode('cp1252').capitalize().encode('cp1252')
# Prints É (assuming your terminal is happy to receive cp1252)
```

Comment: http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/SpecialCasing.txt says that it is not that simple even when locale is not under consideration

Answer (score 1):

`capitalize()` should Just Work™ for Unicode strings.